# Dial code appends to the mobile number in textfield,which is not required.Here I am representing the problem as "+91 +91 1234512345"

Tags: ios, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNlM7.png)When phone number is entered in text field for mobile number of a flutter app, the dial code appends to the mobile number which is not required.Here dial code  comes from "InternationalPhoneNumber" This issue is in iOS only not in Android.Here I am representing the problem as "+91 +91 1234512345". Here the first dial code comes from drop down list and second one is automatically appending to mobile number.How to remove the second dial code from mobile number?

Comment: If your app is behaving in a way you don't like, you would need to write your code differently.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.